# BlazeDS VS REST +JSON

Tags: apache-flex, json, blazeds

Can anyone tell me: What are the advantages/disadvantages of BlazeDS compared to using Java REST web services that return JSON data for a fairly data heavy flex application?

Answer (score 2):

BlazeDS is going to use AMF for encoding data which is incredibly more compact than JSON.  AMF is a binary format so all numeric and date values will be significantly smaller than with JSON.  Also AMF uses string references to save a huge amount of space when sending repetitive text (class/property names).  Additionally class definitions are also referenced only sent once per AMF message.

Besides the size, AMF is also significantly faster to process than JSON, definitely on the client side and most likely on the server side as well.

Basically, if you have a choice to use AMF over JSON, then do it.  If you have to use an existing service that only supports JSON, then it's ok too, but even then if it's a large application or with significant usage, you're better off switching to AMF even for existing services.

Comment: To add more to this, AMF is natively parsed (extremely quick) while JSON is not.  Any string operating is going to take some time no matter which language you're in.  If you want some benchmarks, I suggest you look at [James Ward's Census 2](http://www.jamesward.com/census2/) application to see for yourself.

Comment: JSON is native right now in flex. Also, you can gzip JSON which normally saves about 90% of the size. That actually is also shown in the app mentioned, but differences between AMF and dojo json are not that significant.

Comment: @BartoszRadaczyński the differences are less than they used to be and AMF vs JSON should never be a bottleneck in a real world scenario, but given the option to choose between the two, AMF is better, IMO.